# what should i write in server name in sql server

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2008-r2, server-name

I've installed sql server 2008 r2
But the "server name" field in sqlserver is empty and i can't login to this
What should i write in server name in sql server ?

My account name in windows 7 is

> alaveh

and my PC name is

> alaveh-pc

I've tested

> alaveh , alaveh-pc , local , .\local ,  LocalSystem , (local) ,
>   .\alaveh , .\alaveh-pc

I need your help . Thanks a lot

Comment: What *edition* did you install? Did you name your instance or use a default instance? These are details the people of StackOverflow simply don't know because we didn't watch you perform your installation and can't see your machine now. My first guess wp would be to try `.\SQLEXPRESS` but that is merely a guess. You need to provide more details.

Comment: hi . thank you . SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition . its not express so .\SQLEXPRESS Will not work .

Comment: If you have just installed a default instance, just the server name should do. Are you accessing it locally or remotely?

Comment: Did you add your account to the list of administrators during the installation?

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL Server Management Studio:

1. Run `File -> Connect Object Explorer...`
2. Click `Server Name` and choose `<Browse for more...>`
3. Select `Network Servers` tab
4. Wait until server names list will be retrieved and expand `Database Engine` node in a tree
5. Find server which name starts as your PC name - `alaveh-pc`
6. Select it, press `OK` button and then connect with proper credentials which is known only for you